# Constructing JSON with JQuery from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to construct the following JSON within JQuery with a editable table but I don't know where should I begin, since my heading, the number of boarding zone(columns) and the number of route serial(rows) changes all the time, therefore I have to manually pull out the data and construct the JSON per row. Thank you in advances for any comment and reply.

```
{  "name": txtRouteName.val(),
  "serial": [
    { "rsn": "X100", "boardingzone": [
      { "name": "Foo", "time": "8:00" },
      { "name": "Bar", "time": "8:15"}
    ] },
    { "rsn": "X101", "boardingzone": [
      { "name": "Foo", "time": "9:00" },
      { "name": "Bar", "time": "9:15"}
    ] }
  ] 
};
```

where the table are displayed as follow:

```
<table id="table1">
   <tr>
   <td>RSN</td>
       <td>Foo</td>
       <td>Bar</td>
   </tr>                        
  <tr>
      <td>X100</td>
      <td>8:00</td>  
      <td>8:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>X101</td>
      <td>9:00</td>  
      <td>9:15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I suggest you use `th` for your table headings:

```
<table id="table1">

   <tr>
       <th>RSN</th>
       <th>Foo</th>
       <th>Bar</th>
   </tr>
```

Then you could:

```
function parseTable(table) {
    // Helper function to extract the text content of a cell
    function getText(i, cell) { return $(cell).text().trim() };

    // Get the text of the headings as an array
    var headings = $(table).find('tr:eq(0)').find('th').map(getText);

    // Get the text of the values as an array of arrays (values in rows)
    var values = $(table).find('tr:gt(0)').map(function(i, row) {
        return $(row).find('td').map(getText);
    });

    // Map the data according to these rules:
    // One object per row, with `boardingzone` keeping an array of the values
    var result = $.map(values, function(row) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[headings[0]] = row[0];
        obj.boardingzone = $.map(row.slice(1), function(value, i) {
            return {
                name: headings[i + 1],
                time: value
            }
        });
        return obj;
    });

    return result;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(parseTable("#table1")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and comment, I did a editable column with <th> before however for some random reason my heading columns won't increase in number as the drop down list value changes. For that I have changed the <th> to <td>.

Comment: Ok, then just change `th` to `td` in the line `var headings = $(table).find('tr:eq(0)').find('th').map(getText);`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate rows and cells:

```
$("#table1 tr").each(function(){
         //Rows action
         $(this).children("td").each(function (){
         //Cells action
         });
});
```

If you are in the first row then there are field names. if you are in the first cell of row you're reading rsv, otherwise youre reading boardingzone.

Comment: I thought of that but I don't really know how to extend my rsn into the serial array with the boarding zone array in the serial array